# How can I read the Get value from url parameter

Tags: php, query-string

How can I read value in get parameter

`http://www.localhost/type=Cars,-Vans-&-SUVs`

When I am trying to read `type` value from get URL I am not able to read from `&`.

Please suggest how to read type variable value in Get method.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems as if the link in your post is not correct, please take another look at your post and add the correct link.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is , that & is a delimiter between GET-Keys.

You have to urlencode the value of the "type" or any other key in your URL:

```
Cars,-Vans-&-SUVs
```

is urlencoded:

```
Cars%2C-Vans-%26-SUVs
```

if you try to get the value, only urldecode the value.

In PHP the functions are `urlencode()` and `urldecode()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a ? sign before the [GET parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) so if you want your type to be cars, the link should be:

```
http://www.localhost/?type=cars
```

If you need more than one parameter you should add it with an & sign

```
http://www.localhost/?type=cars&wheels=4
```

From your php file you then read the variables with $_GET[]

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
$wheels = $_GET['wheels'];
```

If you want all three types inside type parameter you should use

```
http://www.localhost/?type=Cars,-Vans-%26-SUVs
```

## Update:

With:

```
?type=Cars,-Vans-%26-SUVs
```

the result array is:

```
[type] => Cars,-Vans-&-SUVs
```

Comment: but if I want to read value of type as car&wheels

Comment: then make it ?type=car%26wheels where %26 represents the & sign but does not go as delimiter for a different GET parameter

Comment: are you using this in a form or just typing it?